# Pandas: Setting no. of max rows

Tags: python, formatting, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem viewing the following `DataFrame`:

```
n = 100
foo = DataFrame(index=range(n))
foo['floats'] = np.random.randn(n)
foo
```

The problem is that it does not print all rows per default in ipython notebook, but I have to slice to view the resulting rows. Even the following option does not change the output:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
```

Does anyone know how to display the whole array?

Comment: When I run your code in a default (i.e. no special configuration profile) notebook, I get a pretty printed table that is scrollable with all values. FYI, my pandas.__version__ = 0.9.1 (not sure if this matters)

Comment: I meant regular shell, not ipython

Comment: I have a feeling this might be a bug in 0.11+...

Comment: Hi Andy. Has this already been confirmed by Wes? Where can I file this bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I just filed it [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3541), I know there were some last minute changes in 0.11 to the DataFrame repr so I cc'd those in the bug report. Will let you know re workaround.

Comment: For those interested in setting options directly by their attributes, [look at this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47113685/3707607).

Answer (score 557, accepted):

Set `display.max_rows`:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
```

For older versions of pandas (<=0.11.0) you need to change both `display.height` and `display.max_rows`.

```
pd.set_option('display.height', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
```

See also [`pd.describe_option('display')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.describe_option.html).

You can set an option only *temporarily* for this one time like this:

```
from IPython.display import display
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 100, 'display.max_columns', 10):
    display(df) #need display to show the dataframe when using with in jupyter
    #some pandas stuff
```

You can also reset an option back to its default value like this:

`pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')`

And reset all of them back:

`pd.reset_option('all')`

Comment: +1 for the pd.describe_option('display'), I did not know all the options

Comment: Height is now deprecated so the display.max_rows option is enough.

Comment: For anyone only looking at the accepted answer: use `with pd.option_context('display.height', 500, 'display.max_rows', 500):` to only set these temporarily.

Comment: I should correct or give the best way to achieve this. Use None and don't limit to 500.
 
#Temporary display all rows and columns

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows',None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    display(df_facilities) 

The above code will take effect only in the cell containing the code so no need to reset in other cells.

Comment: Not sure if it's a jupyter lab problem, but none of this is working. Only 'display.max_rows' = None does.

Comment: @antonavy I don't know if that is your issue but when setting  `display.max_rows` to an integer, setting also `display.min_rows` is needed to affect how many rows are displayed in a truncated view (when `max_rows` is exceeded).

Comment: In newest versions of Pandas setting the `display.height` raises an exception now.

Comment: This is terrible, unusable. Would it be so difficult to add a parameter `display(this, n_rows=2 zillions)`?

Comment: have made this a utility for my jupyter setup.

Comment: With newer versions of Pandas, you can use the slightly less visually distracting `pd.options.display.max_rows = 500`

Comment: Also, setting [`min_rows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57861411/1048186) to the same value as `max_rows` seems to work well: dataframes less than `min_rows` still use fewer-than-min rows, and dateframes with more than `max_rows` use `min_rows` in their collapsed form.

Comment: But even at a command prompt, I recommend using the option context as it can quickly become tedious to see all that output except in the few places you want it, especially for `min_rows`.  e.g. `with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 100,'display.min_rows', 100): print(df)`

Comment: Just wanna note that this did not work for me in PyCharm's notebook editor. But then I found that you can click on "10 rows" in the header of the display area and select a "Page Size" from a range of number e.g. 100 or All.

Answer (score 76):

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
df
```

**Does not work** in Jupyter!
Instead use:

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
df.head(500)
```

Comment: In https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28654#issuecomment-536094705 is an explanation, why that happens.

You have to set also `display.min_rows`, because `display.max_rows` is the threshold, when you display `display.min_rows` number of roles.

I have no idea, how they came up with these names.

Comment: The first line now seems to work in jupyter notebook without the head() trick.

Comment: The first one works if len(df) < 500

Answer (score 73):

Personally, I like setting the options directly with an assignment statement as it is easy to find via tab completion thanks to iPython. I find it hard to remember what the exact option names are, so this method works for me.

For instance, all I have to remember is that it begins with `pd.options`

```
pd.options.<TAB>
```

[image]

Most of the options are available under `display`

```
pd.options.display.<TAB>
```

[image]

From here, I usually output what the current value is like this:

```
pd.options.display.max_rows
60
```

I then set it to what I want it to be:

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 100
```

Also, you should be aware of the context manager for options, which temporarily sets the options inside of a block of code. Pass in the option name as a string followed by the value you want it to be. You may pass in any number of options in the same line:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 100, 'display.max_columns', 10):
    some pandas stuff
```

You can also reset an option back to its default value like this:

```
pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')
```

And reset all of them back:

```
pd.reset_option('all')
```

It is still perfectly good to set options via `pd.set_option`. I just find using the attributes directly is easier and there is less need for `get_option` and `set_option`.

Comment: `with pd.option_context` is the cleanest method among these answers; least side effects.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you are doing in your notebook, but I did find the context manager so useful that I wrapped it in a function and used `display(df)` within.

Comment: Pointing out this solution does not work if the Pandas `style` methods are used. `df.style.format(precision = 1)` will show all rows regardless of the context settings.

Answer (score 29):

I don't know why nobody mentioned this.

You should also set `'display.min_rows'`.

```
pd.set_option('display.min_rows', 500)  # <-add this!
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
```

---

If `total number of rows` **>** `display.max_rows`,

then, setting only `display.max_rows` would **not** work.

(Yeah, it's confusing. This should be modified.)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you have 2000 rows, and want to show 500, confusingly you need to set `min_rows`.

Comment: This solved the issue for me as well. Only setting `max_rows` does not always work. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 19):

It was already pointed in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424493/pandas-setting-no-of-max-rows#comment87926394_16433953) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47113685/7649076), but I'll try to give a more direct answer to the question:

```
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 100
foo = pd.DataFrame(index=range(n))
foo['floats'] = np.random.randn(n)

with pd.option_context("display.max_rows", foo.shape[0]):
    display(foo)
```

[pandas.option_context](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.option_context.html) is available since pandas 0.13.1 ([pandas 0.13.1 release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/release.html?highlight=option_context#pandas-0-13-1)).
According to [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html?highlight=option_context),

> [it] allow[s] you to execute a codeblock with a set of options that revert to prior settings when you exit the with block.

Answer (score 16):

to set unlimited number of rows use

> None

i.e.,

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

now the notebook will display all the rows in all datasets within the notebook ;)

Similarly you can set to show all columns as

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

now if you use run the cell with only dataframe with out any head or tail tags
as

```
df
```

then it will show all the rows and columns in the dataframe `df`

Comment: Isn't it `max_columns` ?

Comment: Thanks @igorkf for update, I've made the changes
Thanks for reading my post, happy learning

Answer (score 9):

As @hanleyhansen noted in a comment, as of version 0.18.1, the `display.height` option is deprecated, and says "use `display.max_rows` instead". So you just have to configure it like this:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
```

See the [Release Notes — pandas 0.18.1 documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/release.html):

> Deprecated display.height, display.width is now only a formatting option does not control triggering of summary, similar to < 0.11.0.

Answer (score 7):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923958/604687) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19124601/604687), there is no need to hack settings. It is much simpler to write:

```
print(foo.to_string())
```

Comment: You shouldn't be converting it to string. It's not what Andy asked for.

Comment: @simtim Andy asked how to "display the whole array". This will do that and is *much* simpler than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

I would use a context manager to set these options so that I can control which df should be affected.

```
with pd.option_context('display.min_rows', 50, 'display.max_columns', None):
    display(df)
```

Also, instead of `display.max_rows` use `display.min_rows` instead. This should work without setting `display.max_rows`.

Answer (score 3):

pd.options.display.max_rows = None

This would display all the rows