# Jupyter Notebook Ipython: Groupby based on the values alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I am using jupyter notebook first time. I tried to groupby one column of csv and get the count of the values. i got the below result with this code.

```
import pandas
pandas.read_csv('a.csv', sep=',')
df.groupby('name').name.count()
name
>Aa</TOPONYM>                 4
>Aachen</TOPONYM>             5
>Aartselaar</TOPONYM>         1
>Abadan</TOPONYM>             1
>Abaya</TOPONYM>              1
>Abba</TOPONYM>              12
>Abbey                        2
>Abbeydale</TOPONYM>          1
>Abbot</TOPONYM>              2
>Abbots                       3
>Abbotsford</TOPONYM>        22
>Abbotsinch</TOPONYM>         5
>Abbotts                      1
>Abel</TOPONYM>               1
>Aberchirder</TOPONYM>        2
>Aberdare</TOPONYM>           3
>Aberdeen                     1
>Aberdeen</TOPONYM>         163
>Aberdeenshire</TOPONYM>    286
>Aberdour</TOPONYM>           9
>Aberfan</TOPONYM>            1
>Aberfeldy</TOPONYM>         16
>Abergavenny</TOPONYM>        4
>Aberlady                     1
>Aberlady</TOPONYM>           3
>Abernethy</TOPONYM>          1
>Abertay                      1
>Abertillery</TOPONYM>        6
>Abha</TOPONYM>               2
>Abidjan</TOPONYM>           10
                           ... 
>Zakho</TOPONYM>             20
>Zakopane</TOPONYM>           1
>Zambezi                      2
>Zambezi</TOPONYM>            8
>Zambia</TOPONYM>            19
>Zamboanga</TOPONYM>          4
>Zandak</TOPONYM>             3
>Zanzibar</TOPONYM>          11
>Zaragosa</TOPONYM>           1
>Zaragoza</TOPONYM>           4
>Zeebrugge</TOPONYM>         28
>Zeeland</TOPONYM>            2
>Zemun</TOPONYM>              1
>Zenica</TOPONYM>            12
>Zermatt</TOPONYM>            5
>Zetland</TOPONYM>            1
>Zhizhong</TOPONYM>           1
>Zhongshan</TOPONYM>          2
>Zhuhai</TOPONYM>             1
>Zimbabwe</TOPONYM>         377
>Znamenskoye</TOPONYM>        1
>Zoetermeer</TOPONYM>         1
>Zola</TOPONYM>               1
>Zomba</TOPONYM>              3
>Zulu</TOPONYM>               1
>Zululand</TOPONYM>           2
>Zuni</TOPONYM>               2
>Zurich</TOPONYM>            86
>Zvornik</TOPONYM>            3
>Zwolle</TOPONYM>             1
Name: name, Length: 8585, dtype: int64
```

is it possible to get the counts alphabet by alphabet, first I should run the command with alphabet a and it should give all values with a then next b and so on. or if it's possible to get the values skipping starting 100 values.

My real data looks like this:

```
<TOPONYM    geonameid="2657540" lat="51.24827"  lon="-0.76389"  >Aldershot</TOPONYM>    
<TOPONYM    geonameid="3037854" lat="49.9"  lon="2.3"   >Amiens</TOPONYM>   
<TOPONYM    geonameid="6216857" lat="-43.59832" lon="171.55011" >Alaska</TOPONYM>   
<TOPONYM    geonameid="3037854" lat="49.9"  lon="2.3"   >Amiens</TOPONYM>   
<TOPONYM    geonameid="2759794" lat="52.37403"  lon="4.88969"   >Amsterdam</TOPONYM>    
<TOPONYM    geonameid="7216668" lat="28.0106"   lon="-82.1184"  >Alabama</TOPONYM>  
<TOPONYM    geonameid="5884078" lat="48.98339"  lon="-73.34907" >Ally</TOPONYM> 
<TOPONYM    geonameid="2507480" lat="36.7525"   lon="3.04197"   >Algiers</TOPONYM>  
<TOPONYM    geonameid="2759794" lat="52.37403"  lon="4.88969"   >Amsterdam</TOPONYM>    
<TOPONYM    geonameid="2759794" lat="52.37403"  lon="4.88969"   >Amsterdam</TOPONYM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select first letter by `str[1]` and then use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = pandas.read_csv('a.csv')

a = df['name'].str[0].value_counts().rename_axis('alph').reset_index(name='count')
```

Another solutions with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by second letter:

```
a = df['name'].groupby(df['name'].str[0]).count().reset_index(name='count')
```

---

```
a = df['name'].groupby(df['name'].str[0]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'counts'. this is the error that I received

Comment: I add solutions instead `df.groupby('name').name.count()`, so try remove it.

Comment: I ran this neither it gave an error nor it gave any result.

Comment: oops, typo, `count` not `counts`

Comment: I got it based on alphabets , is it possible to get based on values and in alphabetical order

Comment: OK, what is `print (df['name'].head(3).tolist())` ?

Comment: or if you can tell me, if I am able to find the values with my own code that i mentioned in my question but using descending order and skipping 100 values of starting

Comment: I have an idea. Is possible add to question `print (df[['name']].head(10)` and then desired output from this first 10 rows?

Comment: this gave me [nan, nan, 'Hejaz</TOPONYM']

Comment: for remove first 100 rows need `df = pandas.read_csv('a.csv', skiprows=range(1,101))`

Comment: Hmm, then need `str[0]` instead `str[1]`, because first char is not `>`.

Comment: `using descending order` do you need sort `df.groupby('name').name.count()` ? Then need `df.groupby('name').name.count().sort_values(ascending=False)`

Comment: I have removed > from the data now, so first letter would be alphabet in this column

Comment: using descending order do you need sort df.groupby('name').name.count() ? Then need df.groupby('name').name.count().sort_values(ascending=False) yes it worked now I am looking to skip starting 50 rows of this result

Comment: Then need `df.groupby('name').name.count().sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[50:]`

Comment: Thanks this worked. now there is one more question .

Comment: in this data I have one more column that contains different values for this column with location names. is it possible to sort these location names with that column values and get the counts?

Comment: Not sure if understand, can you add data sample, 5-6 rows? What is `sort these location names with that column values` ?

Comment: <TOPONYM geonameid="2657540" lat="51.24827" lon="-0.76389" >Aldershot</TOPONYM>
 
<TOPONYM geonameid="3037854" lat="49.9" lon="2.3" >Amiens</TOPONYM> 

<TOPONYM geonameid="6216857" lat="-43.59832" lon="171.55011" >Alaska</TOPONYM> 

<TOPONYM geonameid="3037854" lat="49.9" lon="2.3" >Amiens</TOPONYM> 

<TOPONYM geonameid="2759794" lat="52.37403" lon="4.88969" >Amsterdam</TOPONYM>

Comment: Thanks, can you add this data to question, because bad formating in comments with desired output?

Comment: It is one column only? And what is desired output?

Comment: these are five different columns first with toponym, second with geoid, third with latitude, fourth with longitude and fifth with names.
my desired output is to group by the name column and geoid column, because there are names with same geoid as well some different geoids, so I want to sort them out.

Comment: OK, then need `df.groupby(['name','geoid']).name.count().sort_values(ascending=False)‌​.iloc[50:]`

Comment: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ascening' error

Comment: i made some changes and it worked. is it possible to extract let's suppose only Amsterdam values?

Comment: I think need `b = df.xs('Amsterdam', level=0, axis=0)`, more info [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)

Comment: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'get_loc_level'

Comment: If `Amsterdam` is value in column then use `df = df[df['name'] == 'Amsterdam']`

Comment: and for check substrings `df = df[df['name'].str.contains( 'Amsterdam')]`

Comment: with the first command it gave plain output without any rows.

Comment: It means no match, maybe traling space. So need second one.

Comment: Hmmm, if value `Amsterdam` in column `name`, it is weird. If check `print (df['name'].head(20))` there are cities?

Comment: Series([], Name: name, dtype: object) this is the output i received.. 
I think there is some error

Comment: ok it gave the list of starting 20 names now. but with the command we entered string containing Amsterdam. it shows 
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values.

Comment: First means no data and for second need `df = df[df['name'].str.contains( 'Amsterdam', na=False)]`

Comment: :) you are welcome! But please dont give me some likes like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) ;)

Comment: can you tell me if it's possible to widen the range of result?

Comment: more columns? Then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33375383/2901002)

Comment: when I tried this import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('a.csv', sep=',')
grouped=df.groupby('name').name.count()
ax = grouped.sort_values(ascending=False)
print (ax)
it gave me result only 50 to 60 lines with ... in between

Comment: I am looking for all the names to appear in the result file

Comment: It is only not display, check [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16424493/2901002)

Comment: import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('a.csv', sep=',')
grouped=df.groupby('name').name.count()
grouped = grouped.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
ax = grouped.sort_values(ascending=False)

print (ax)

I added this in my script and it gave error >
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_option'

Comment: typo, need `pandas.set_option`

Comment: OK, go home, so no answering for comments ;) Good luck!