# pandas pd.options.display.max_rows not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I’m using pandas 0.25.1 in Jupyter Lab and the maximum number of rows I can display is 10, regardless of what `pd.options.display.max_rows` is set to.

However, if `pd.options.display.max_rows` is set to less than 10 it takes effect and if `pd.options.display.max_rows = None` then all rows show.

Any idea how I can get a `pd.options.display.max_rows` of more than 10 to take effect?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

### Final answer as of `pandas v0.25.1`

- To display all the rows, set `max_rows` greater than the number of rows in the `DataFrame`.
- To display more than 10 rows when the dataframe is truncated, set `min_rows` greater than 10.
- With more than 200 rows of data, if `max_rows` is 200 and `min_rows` is 20, 10 from the head and 10 from the tail will be displayed.
- With more than 200 rows of data, if `max_rows` is 200 and `min_rows` is `None`, 100 from the head and 100 from the tail will be displayed.

### Discovery & Notes:

Both `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', x)` and `pd.options.display.max_rows = x` (where x is some number), should work.

- FYI: the default is 10 rows, as per [pandas.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html)
- [Options and settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html)
- This is also in `Jupyter Lab`

#### Other useful `pandas` options:

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 200)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)
pd.set_option('display.min_rows', 100)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', True)
```

#### `get.options` to return the current value:

```py
pd.get_option("display.max_rows")
```

#### Update:

- After some discovery testing, the setting only displays more rows, if the setting is greater than the number of rows in the `DataFrame`.
- If `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)`, but the `DataFrame` has 200 rows, only 10 will show up.
- If `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 200)`, but the `DataFrame` has 100 rows, all 100 will display.

#### Per the pandas docs:

- `display.max_rows`: default=60
- This sets the maximum number of rows pandas should output when printing out various output. For example, this value determines whether the repr() for a dataframe prints out fully or just a truncated or summary repr. ‘None’ value means unlimited.
- `display.min_rows`: default=10
- The numbers of rows to show in a truncated repr (when max_rows is exceeded). Ignored when max_rows is set to None or 0. When set to None, follows the value of max_rows.
- `display.large_repr`: default=truncate
- For DataFrames exceeding `max_rows`/`max_cols`, the repr (and HTML repr) can show a truncated table (the default), or switch to the view from `df.info()` (the behaviour in earlier versions of pandas). allowable settings, [‘truncate’, ‘info’]

Answer (score -3):

min_rows displays the number of rows to be displayed from the top (head) and from the bottom (tail) it will be evenly split..despite putting in an odd number. If you only want a set number of rows to be displayed without reading it into the memory,

another way is to use `nrows = 'putnumberhere'`.

`e.g. results = pd.read_csv('ex6.csv', nrows = 5) # display 5 rows from the top 0 - 4`

If the dataframe has about 100 rows and you want to display only the first 5 rows from the top...NO TAIL use `.nrows`

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question, which is _Any idea how I can get a `pd.options.display.max_rows` of more than 10 to take effect?_. Additionally, only reading a certain number of rows to simulate the effect is not efficient.