# how can i open the output cell in a new tab in vscode using jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[code cell and output cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxQeS.png)
this is the cell where I want to know if there are duplicates in my dataset however the output cell doesn't expand to show me the full output.
I am using jupyter notebook and pandas.

Comment: This is a pandas option, not a VSCode thing. This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57860775/pandas-pd-options-display-max-rows-not-working-as-expected#57861411

Answer (score 2):

I found out I can just open the variables tab and choose which variable output I want to fully see in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a vscode issue, to track if you have duplicates, you can you a set () object and compare the length of the set with the length of your column, if the length of the set is equal to the length of the column, then there is no duplicates.

otherwise, you can use a Counter object:

```
from collections import Counter 

Counter(df["a"])
```

which will give you the frequency of each item in your columns

suppose this is your dataframe :

```
In [8]: df                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[8]: 
   a
0  a
1  b
2  b
3  c
4  d
5  e
```

then applying the above code will give you this result:

```
Out[9]: Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1})
```

which is clearly a method to check duplicates

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Comment: if you know a trick to open the output cell in a new tab so I can see all of the output I would appreciate it, thanks again.

Comment: you can write the result in a file if you want: