# Check sum of null values of large data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I tired to check null values of my data frame(house) which has 81 columns but
`house.isnull().sum()`  display only few columns data.

```
MSSubClass         0
MSZoning           0
LotFrontage      259
LotArea            0
Street             0
                ... 
MoSold             0
YrSold             0
SaleType           0
SaleCondition      0
SalePrice          0
Length: 80, dtype: int64
```

I tired to run for loop to get the all columns in one go but couldn't do that. Appreciate your help

```
null_check = house.columns
for ncheck in null_check:
    print(ncheck.isnull().sum())
```

Comment: Look at [How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Not really .. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this line before you get the output

pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)

See this other article on this

[Pandas: Setting no. of max rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424493/pandas-setting-no-of-max-rows)

Comment: Thanks for reply but  it provide an error "ValueError: Must provide an even number of non-keyword arguments"

Comment: Sorry I missed a parameter. Check out that other link on this question.

Comment: Yes it worked :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.isna()` and call `sum` on axis=0, if needed, use `.to_frame()` to create dataframe out of it.

```py
df.isna().sum(axis=0)

Item         0
Currency     20
Year Rate    3
dtype: int64
```