# show all unique value from column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I try to show all value from a dataframe column with this code `combinaison_df['coalesce'].unique()`

but I got this result :

```
array([1.12440191, 0.54054054, 0.67510549, ..., 1.011378  , 1.39026812,
       1.99637024])
```

I need to see all the values.  Do you have an idea to do?

Thanks

Comment: If it's a long set of values like this appears to be, there really isn't much you can do just by calling `.unique()`. You can update Pandas display options, but if there are a ton of values it might not be practical. Your best/easiest bet is to iterate over the unique values and print them to the console.

Comment: You also have the option of dumping the unique values to a file using `np.savetxt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Setting no. of max rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424493/pandas-setting-no-of-max-rows)

Answer (score -1):

If I have this situation but don't want to change it for every print() statement I found this solution with a context manager quite handy:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
    print(combinaison_df['coalesce'].unique())
```