# FastF1 Data Output is incomplete

Tags: python, pandas

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import fastf1.plotting


fastf1.plotting.setup_mpl()

# load a session and its telemetry data
session = fastf1.get_session(2021, 'United States Grand Prix', 'Q')
session.load()

ver_lap = session.laps.pick_driver('VER').pick_fastest()

ver_tel = ver_lap.get_car_data().add_distance()

print(ver_tel['Distance'], ver_tel['Speed'])
```

When printing the information, the output is very limited and displays only some information. As follows:

```
0         0.000000
1        15.466667
2        31.400000
3        47.800000
4        64.400000
          ...     
382    5378.533056
383    5391.533056
384    5405.266389
385    5419.466389
386    5434.266389
Name: Distance, Length: 387, dtype: float64 0      229
1      232
2      239
3      246
4      249
      ... 
382    188
383    195
384    206
385    213
386    222
Name: Speed, Length: 387, dtype: int64
```

How do I get all the plot points (x,y)

Any help will be great!

Comment: Has nothing to do with matplotlib. rather this is pandas.

Comment: Oh. Thank you @BigBen. Can you guide me on how can I solve that then?

Comment: My guess would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424493/pandas-setting-no-of-max-rows).

Comment: Thanks! But I think with that I don't know what should be 'pd' since I am never importing pandas in mine. @BigBen