# abstracting 2 columns from a dataset with a specific sample of 10

Tags: python, dataset

[this is a sample diabetics dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA7Ve.png)

I want to get only the 2 mentioned columns as the output but i am not sure about the code for that

**df.get("gender", "heart_disease")**

I tried this and the code is working but I am only getting the output of gender want only 10 sample outputs. how do i get that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Setting no. of max rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424493/pandas-setting-no-of-max-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, subset the pandas data frame using the `df[list of columns]` notation then sample

```
df[['gender', 'heart_disease']].sample(10)
```

Comment: i am trying to plot a graph for the same 2 columns and i used this code -  plt.figure(figsize = (3,3))
df[["gender", "heart_disease"]].plot(kind = "bar")
plt.xlabel("heart_disease")
plt.ylabel("gender");    This is Throwing an error, what is the right code for this?

Comment: pls help with the above comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
df[["gender", "heart_disease"]]
```